# Control de arreglo en plantilla Jade

Tags: socket, jade, socket.io

Estoy realizando una aplicación donde leo una base de datos en MySQL (MariaDB) y el resultado (un arreglo) lo renderizo a una plantilla en jade.

Trato de crear un `slider` para 8 imagenes en 4 columnas Bootstrap y 2 imágenes con información descriptiva en 8 columnas de una sola fila. Con datos estáticos lo hago y funciona el envio de la información desde la base de datos hasta la plantilla en Jade (pug) y muestra el pantallazo como quiero pero al utilizar **socket.io** no funciona.

Utilizo **socket.io** para actualizar los resultados de la lectura de la base de datos y,por lo tanto empleo un script en la plantilla jade para declarar una **variable slidder** y asignarle un conjunto de HTML junto con las variables transmitidas a la plantilla jade por el socket.

No encuentro la forma para manejar este arreglo  con contenido HTML enviado desde la app en nodejs hacia un DIV contenedor.

**renderizado en la app (node js**)

```
app.get('/punto2',function(peticion,respuesta){
// Doing count register with estado=0
var query = client.query(conteoquery, function(error, result){
     if(error){
        var query = client.query(aceros, function(err, result) {
              console.log("Registro actualizado!!");
              console.log("2. Cambiados: "+result.changedRows+"; Afectados: "+ result.affectedRows);
            });
        throw error;
     }else{
           // Doing the database query
          client.query(cadquery,function selectCb(err, dattos, fields) {
          // Los datos recibidos estan en dattos
              if (err) {
                      var query = client.query(aceros, function(err, result) {
                      console.log("2. Cambiados: "+result.changedRows+"; Afectados: "+ result.affectedRows);
                   });
                  throw err;
              }
              else{
                  for(var i=0;i<dattos.length;i++)
                  {
                      console.log(dattos[i].cab)
                  }
                  ip=peticion.hostname;    
                  console.log("/punto2. ip server: ",ip);
                 **respuesta.render('indexn2sck2.jade',{data:dattos,ip:ip});**
              }
          })
      }
});
});
```

**el socket**

```
var pollingLoop = function() {
 // Doing the database query
 var cadquery='SELECT * from articulos WHERE estado <> TRUE limit 1,8';
  var query = client.query(cadquery),
    users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query
  //var query1=client.query(cadquery1);
  // setting the query listeners
  query
    .on('error', function(err) {
      // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
      console.log("Error en pollingLoop: "+err);
    /*  updateSockets(err);*/
    })
    .on('result', function(user) {
      // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
      //console.log("onresult ");
      users.push(user);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
      if (connectionsArray.length) {
        pollingTimer = setTimeout(pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL);
       //  console.log("onend ");
        updateSockets({       
          turnos: users
        });
        } else {

        console.log('El Servidor fue parado porque no existen mas conexiones');
      }
    });
}
var updateSockets = function(data) {
  // adding the time of the last update
    data.time = new Date();
    console.log("updateSockets: ",data.turnos[0].nombre);
    //console.log('Pushing new data to the clients connected ( connections amount = %s ) - %s', connectionsArray.length , data.time);
    // sending new data to all the sockets connected
    console.log("%s %s %s // %s %s %s",data.time.getFullYear(),data.time.getMonth()+1,data.time.getDay()+1,data.time.getHours(),data.time.getMinutes(),data.time.getSeconds());
    connectionsArray.forEach(function(tmpSocket) {
        tmpSocket.volatile.emit('notification', data);
    });
};
```

**la plantilla jade (pug): index.jade**

```
body

        #titulo.titulo
        #contenedor.contenedor
            img(src=`img/nombre.png`, alt=`nombre`)
            script(src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js")
            script(src='http://#{ip}:7200/socket.io/socket.io.js')
            script.
                var slidder;
                var ips='http://#{ip}:7200/socket.io/';
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    // create a new websocket
                    var socket = io.connect(ips);
                    // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
                    socket.on('notification', function (data) {
                        **slidder**=`<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"><ol class="carousel-indicators"><li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li><li data-target="#carousel-1"data-slide-to="1"></li><li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="2"></li><li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="3"></li><li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="4"></li><li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="5"></li><li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="6"></li><li data-target="#carousel-1" data-slide-to="7"></li></ol><div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"><div class="item active"><img src="img/#{data[0].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 1"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[0].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[0].generales}</p></div></div><div class="item"><img src="img/#{data[1].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 2"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[1].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[1].generales}</p></div></div><div class="item"><img src="img/#{data[2].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 3"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[2].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[2].generales}</p></div></div><div class="item"><img src="img/#{data[3].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 4"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[3].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[3].generales}</p></div></div><div class="item"><img src="img/#{data[4].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 5"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[4].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[4].generales}</p></div></div><div class="item"><img src="img/#{data[5].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 6"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[5].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[5].generales}</p></div></div><div class="item"><img src="img/#{data[6].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 7"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[6].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[6].generales}</p></div></div><div class="item"><img src="img/#{data[7].imagen}" class="img-responsive"  alt="slide 8"><div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><h3>#{data[7].nombre}</h3><br><p>#{data[7].generales}</p></div></div></div></div></div><br><div class="col-md-8"><div class="item1"><div class="cab"><div class="well well-sm"><span class="dattum">#{data[0].cab}</span></div></div><div class="propi"><div class="configuracion">Codigo:<span class="dattum">#{data[0].codigo}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Nombre:<span class="dattum">#{data[0].nombre}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Potencia:<span class="dattum">#{data[0].potencia}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Velocidad:<span class="dattum">#{data[0].velocidad}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Alimentacion:<span class="dattum">#{data[0].alimentacion}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Uso:<span class="dattum">span #{data[0].uso}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Generales:<span class="dattum">#{data[0].generales}</span></div></div><div class="imagen"><img src="/img/#{data[0].imagen}"  class="img-responsive" alt="slide 1"></div><div class="pie"><div class="well well-sm">#{data[0].pie}</div></div></div><div class="item2"><div class="cab"><div class="well well-sm"><span class="dattum">#{data[1].cab}</span></div></div><div class="propi"><div class="configuracion">Codigo:<span class="dattum">#{data[1].codigo}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Nombre:<span class="dattum">#{data[1].nombre}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Potencia:<span class="dattum">#{data[1].potencia}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Velocidad:<span class="dattum">#{data[1].velocidad}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Alimentacion:<span class="dattum">#{data[1].alimentacion}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Uso:<span class="dattum">span #{data[1].uso}</span></div><div class="configuracion">Generales:<span class="dattum">#{data[1].generales}</span></div></div><div class="imagen"><img src="/img/#{data[1].imagen}"  class="img-responsive" alt="slide 1"></div><div class="pie"><div class="well well-sm">#{data[1].pie}</div></div></div></div></div></div>`;
**$('#contenedor').html(slidder);**
                    });

                });
        #pie.pie
          img(src='img/nombre.png', width='20%', height='7%', alt='citturn' style='float:left')
```

Donde slider es la variable y los datos provenientes de app.js están nombrados

```
#data[0].nombre
#data[0].cab
```

etc.

Empleo direccionamiento local para bootstrap y para jquery.

**Errores**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La data del socket llega hasta el archivo html renderizado pero no lo puedo mostrar. Agradezco su ayuda. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor, alguna sugerencia?. Ampliación?. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, los problemas tenían que ver con indentación, en el caso de Jade, con la estructura de las variables y la ubicación del script.

El script debe estar al final, justo antes del cierre de body o garantizar que se cargue completamente la página.
Las variables para HTML deben ser el nombre y para Jade

```
#{nombreDeVariable}
```

En el script a los  `getElementByID.innerHTML` se les deben asignar las variables como si fuera HTML (solo el nombre).

Utilizo una variable para trabajar un arreglo y viaja en el objeto data por socket. Esta variable me tocó asignarla a una variable local antes de trabajar los elementos  del arreglo con los innerHTML. Aquí también tenía un problema de desbordamiento del valor.

Se puede trabajar con o sin jQuery. Doy por solucionada la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Pues seguí tratando por cualquier medio que encontrará en internet y creo haber encontrado una solución trabajando con javascript a pelo y con document.getElementById y su versión para imagen document.getElementById('mimg').src="../img/"+"amoladora1.jpg";
            document.getElementById('mimg').width="300";
            document.getElementById('mimg').height="300";

Creo que tengo que pasar los archivos de jade(pug) a HTML pues por aquí me ha funcionado. En unos días publicaré el camino escogido.